# Understanding the equivalence of a Turing machine and an enumerating machine

Tags: turing-machines

The normal argument for a decidable language to build an enumerating machine is given as follows:

Let $M$ be a Turing machine which decides a language $L$, and let $s_1,s_2,\ldots$ be a list of all strings in $\Sigma^{*}$.

Consider the following enumerating machine:

- Ignore the input
- Repeat the following for $i = 1,2,3,\ldots$:

  1. Run $M$ on $s_i$
  2. If it accepts, print out $s_i$

This is what I see as a standard way of building an enumerating machine in case of decidable Turing machine.

I have few doubts about it:

1. How are we going to run $M$ on $s_i$? Are we going to write $s_1, s_2,\ldots$ one by one on enumerating machine working tape?
2. Is an enumerating machine made to run on all words in $\Sigma^{*}$  one by one?

If yes, then consider the enumerating machine constructed for a general Turing machine. The standard way is:

- Ignore the input
- Repeat the following for $i=1,2,3,\dots$:
- Run $M$ for $i$ steps on each input $s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots$
- If any computations accept, print out the corresponding $s_j$

The above is a standard way also mentioned in the Sipser book.

Now here how are we making $M$ on $s_1,s_2,s_3$, say in step 3?

Will this go to enumerating machine working tape?

Will the working tape be generated by the enumerating machine or fed as in in the case of a Turing machine?

3. If enumerating machine is not made to run on all words in $\Sigma^{*}$  one by one,
   then in the above construction of our enumerating machine, how are we going to get the words $s_1,s_2,\ldots$ on its working tape?

I am confused about the way enumerating machine works.